# use ros_arduino_bridge with other hardwares

Tags: ros, ros-arduino-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone
I want to use ros_arduino_bridge stack by Patrick Goebel for my mobile robot base controller. There are two hardwares that patrick has used in it. Pololu VNH5019 dual motor controller shield (http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/2502) or Pololu MC33926 dual motor shield (http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/2503) for drive the motors and Robogaia Mega Encoder shield (http://www.robogaia.com/two-axis-encoder-counter-mega-shield-version-2.html) for encoders.

Unfortunately the encoder shield is out of stock and both two shields are so expensive from my country because i need to import them.

Is it possible to use other shields for this stack??? I am a new learner in robotics and ROS and some more practical advice can help me because now i am so confused about how to do for my work without these two hardwares  :((((((

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193501/use-ros_arduino_bridge-with-other-hardwares/) by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2014-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's an ongoing discussion about this on the Homebrew Robotics mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hbrobotics/TrasImSJxjU

The bottom line is that this should be doable, provided that you choose a motor shield and encoder shield that are compatible with one another. Mostly this just means that they shouldn't use the same pins, but you may also want to check that they don't use the same timers and hardware interrupts.

From there, you'll probably need to update the arduino sketch for your shield(s) pin configuration.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1